# How to remove all the .txt files in a python list

Tags: python-3.7

I have a list

`all_files = ['0.txt', '1.txt', '10.txt', '100.txt', '1000.txt', '1001.txt', '1002.txt', '1003.txt', '1004.txt', '1005.txt', '1006.txt'...]`

and I would like to know if I only have .txt in there so is there a way to remove all the ".txt" from the list or to check if there is any different data type in this list ?

Comment: `all_files = [i for i in all_files if not i.endswith(".txt")]` ?

Comment: It's working thanks a lot !